# In what order should I install the various washers for my ceiling light?

Tags: light-fixture

I am installing a new dome type ceiling light. I need to sandwich the washer and disc between the glass and nut (see pic). Which of the 2 should go first or rather be kissing the glass - plastic disc or metal washer?

I'm guessing the plastic disc since that would protect the glass from excessive tightening and would also compensate for the curved surface of the dome.

A part of me realizes getting this wrong may not cause issues. but I would like to learn the purpose of these parts, the reason the designers decided to put both a washer and a plastic disc rather than just a washer.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the lamp glass cover installation is:

1. Plastic washer to protect the glass from the metal washer.
2. Metal washer to protect the glass between the plastic washer and nut.
3. Metal nut to secure the fittings.
4. Decorative cover, to cover the nut and washers.
5. Decorative end cap

Answer (score 3):

The plastic (or felt, or leather in an older fixture) goes against the glass to protect it from direct contact with the metal and reduce breakage.